# HyperV > Script power to disconnect network card (not disable!)

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

I look for a powershell script to **disconnect** the network card of Virtual machine running under HyperV. I found several script but it is only for **disable**.

I want to keep my network card 'activated'. By disconnected I want to simulate a network failure such as cable unplugged.

With SCVMM, there is an option to 'disconnect' and it works perfectly (if you open Network control panel in your vm, you will read status is 'Network cable unplugged' and not 'network card disable'). If you can help me to script this with powershell, it would be awesome

Thx for all

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at http://pshyperv.codeplex.com.
This PowerShell module has several cmdlets to manage VM network.